# Opening map in GRASS GIS?

Tags: grass-gis

I am brand new to GRASS GIS (and GIS in general) and I am trying to use this for some real estate research.  However, before even going down that path, I'm attempting to follow the Quick wxGUI tutorial (https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Quick_wxGUI_tutorial) just to see if I can open a map.  I am having difficultly even doing this.  Here is what I'm attempting to do:

- I have installed Grass GIS 7.4.0 in Mint Linux
- I downloaded the 'GRASS 7 full data' in zip format (nc_spm, 145MB)
- I have created a GIS Data Directory i '/home/me/grassdata'
- in the 'grassdata' folder, I have 3 directories (landsat, PERMANENT, user1) and 3 files (CREDITS.txt, HISTORY.txt, VERSION.txt)
- When I open GRASS GIS, I navigate to the 'grassdata' folder, it indicates 'No GRASS location found in /home/me/grassdata'. Create a new location or choose different GRASS database directory'

Which directory do I need to browse to for the 'Grass GIS database directory'?

Also, I don't see 'nc_spm_08' or 'spearfish60'.

Comment: What if you navigate to `/home/me/`? `grassdata` is the LOCATION. The folders within are the MAPSETS.

Comment: Hmm, when I select 'browse', then navigate to /home/me, and then choose 'grassdata', I receive that error.  As mentioned in my post, if I go to the file system in look in the 'grassdata' folder, I have 3 folders, and 3 files.

Comment: Don't choose "grassdata". Choose "me".

Comment: Thank you 'mankoff'!  Ugh, no wonder the most basic step didn't work - the tutuorial or Wiki is incorrect.  I no longer receive the error.

Comment: I want to download the the US Zip boundaries from the US Census Bureau (map with all of the US zip codes mapped out)  Here is the link:
https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger.html

Do I need?
TIGER/Line Shapefiles - New 2017 Shapefile

or 

Cartographic Boundary Shapefiles

When I download and extract either of them, it seems like there a number of files (cpg, dbf, prj, shp, xml, shx) and when I put all of those files into Grass 7 (into the /home/me/grassdata), I'm getting the same error as originally reported even after selecting the 'me' directory as mentioned by 'mankoff'

Comment: I think you missed the step in the wiki where it says: "You'll want to uncompress them first, ideally into a directory called "grassdata" in your home directory. " after you do that, you should be able to choose /home/me/grassdata as your GRASS database, then the locations and mapsets will appear

Comment: Regarding the TIGER data, you'll need to import the shapefile into GRASS as a vector. See `v.in.ogr` and/or `v.import`. Typically you should never need to copy files into the GRASS database. Rather the GRASS import functions do that for you.

Comment: Thanks for this Micha... I think I mentioned earlier that when I uncompress the tl_2017_us_zcta510.zip file I download from the US Census Bureau, it creates 7 files.  I then copy those 7 files into the /home/me/grassdata directory (those are the 'only' files in the 'grassdata' directory).  When I go to open GRASS GIS, I immediately receive the error.

Comment: Moving onto your update about the TIGER data... how do I do any type of importing when I open GRASS and I receive the error message about 'No GRASS location found in /home/me or /home/me/grassdata'?  Again, it looks like I need to first select the 'GRASS GIS database directory' before I can proceed with anything else.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm graduating my comments to a full answer)

Here's the procedure:

1. First delete the grassdata directory. (Make sure you have first moved all the components of the shapefile to somewhere else)
2. Now recreate that directory.
3. Unzip the nc_spm zip file **into that new directory**. BTW, you can also use a smaller subset of that data "nc_spm_basic", downloaded from [here](https://grass.osgeo.org/sampledata/north_carolina/nc_basic_spm_grass7.zip). Since this location will only be used for demos, you can begin with the subset. Later, if you want to go thru all the fancy examples, you can choose to download the full nc_spm.
4. Start GRASS, and select the directory /home/me/grassdata as the GRASS database directory. You should then see the nc_spm location in the left window, and the two mapsets user1 and PERMANENT in the right. Choose user1, and then try some of the GRASS modules to get a feel.
5. Now TIGER: The shapefiles are in a different coordinate system (Long/Lat with the NAD83 datum) from the North Caroline demo location. So you **must** create a new location. Close and restart GRASS, and in the initial window click the "New" button in the center to create a new location. In the New Location window you type in a name, such as "TIGER". Then in the next window choose to "Read projection and datum from a georeferenced file". Click next then browse to where you downloaded and unzipped the TIGER data. (again **NOT** in the grassdata directory). Select the file with the *.shp extension.
6. You will then get a window suggesting to import the shapefile into this new location. You can click Yes, then (when it finishes importing) click "Start GRASS Session". You are now in a GRASS session, running under the TIGER location and PERMANENT mapset.
7. You will now have, beneath the grassdata directory two subdirs: nc_spm, and TIGER. Under the TIGER directory you will see PERMANENT. That's the mapset that contains the imported layers. All of the files and directories under "grassdata" and handled internally by GRASS. So there's no need to touch anything there. Just use the various GRASS import commands to get shapefiles into GRASS.
8. Last comment: Shapefiles, and all other spatial data can be imported **only** into a location/mapset with a matching coordinate system. So you'll import into the TIGER location **only** data that is referenced in Long/Lat NAD83 (AKA epsg code: 4369).
9. To actually display the map layers, shift to the "Data" tab in the Layer Manager window and right-click -> Display layer. Then, in case your region settings are not correct, go back to the Layers tab, right-click -> Zoom to Selected map.

HTH

Comment: regarding #8: Don't `r.import` and `v.import` work with non-matching coordinate systems? It is the other commands (e.g. `r.in.gdal` and `v.in.ogr`) that require the data to match the LOCATION.

Comment: Thank you so much for this info Micha... I couple of things:

- for step 3, I figured out why I could not select /home/me/grassdata.  I need the following directory structure: /home/me/grassdata/nc_basic_spm_grass7 with all of the files in the nc_basic_spm_grass7.  Before, I just put all of the files into /home/me/grassdata without creating a nc_basic_spm_grass7 directory.

Comment: - in step 4, once I click on 'Start GRASS session', 2 windows open; one that has a layers, console, modules, data, and python tab at the bottom of the screen (layer manager) and then another window that has zoom icons, vector items, etc (GIS Map Display).  I don't see any type of map in either window.

Comment: - I then appear to successfully complete step 5 and step 6. Again, once I select 'Start Grass Session' in step 6, 2 windows open again - one window is GRASS GIS Layer Manager that has 5 tabs at the bottom (Layers, Console, Modules, Data, Python), the second window - GRASS GIS Map Display TIGER/PERMANENT.  Again, same as I mentioned in step 4, I don't see any type of map in either window at this stage either.

Comment: - For step 7, you say I should see 2 sub directories below the 'grassdata' directory.  When or where should I see this?  As a reminder, I still have the 2 open windows from step 6.  Do I need to close GRASS open and then reopen it see the the 2 listed folders?  If the answer is 'yes', will this affect my import from step 5?

Thank you

Comment: Thanks to mankof for the correction. Indeed v.import and r.import do CRS reprojection on the fly.

Comment: @gil_happy: Now that you have GRASS working, it's time to go thru some of the online tutorials. i.e. https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/helptext.html. Also look thru the excellent tutorials by NCSU, such as http://ncsu-geoforall-lab.github.io/grass-intro-workshop/.    As for not seeing any maps, I added #9 above.

Comment: Thank you so much Micha!  Step 9 is what I was missing... I can now see a map of the USA, with, I believe with all of of the zip code boundaries.  I say 'believe' because, I don't see any zip code numbers (which might be displayed from the next step), I'm not sure if it is zip code boundaries, or county boundaries (I will have to assume zip code).

Now I want to import or overlay a csv file from Zillow.com.  I didn't see anything in the tutorials that referenced the importing of a csv into GRASS, so I Googled it and found this:
https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Importing_data

Comment: Apparently this has something to do with v.in.ascii.  I have no clue what to do next :-(  I am not sure what I need to do with the CSV data to get it into the map.  It doesn't appear that the csv data has any "quoted" strings that needed to be removed with the script.

In the end, I will have a map with all of the zip code boundaries on one layer, and another layer with all of the data from Zillow.

Comment: First, to import a CSV file as points, there must be two columns with the X and Y coordinates. And these coordinates must be in the same coordinate system as your location.  As explained on the `v.in.ascii` manual page, you need to point to the (full path) of the input CSV file, and specify a name for the output GRASS vector - on the "Required" tab of the GUI window. Then you need to specify which column number is the X and which is the Y on the "Points" tab, as well as the field separator (probably comma) on the "Input format" tab.